# WFS Stored Query: RuntimeException: Parsing failed for PropertyIsEqualTo: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: geoserver, wfs

My goal is to filter data using WFS and `Stored Queries`. I want to set the value for 4 properties via a GET variable in the URL and filter them with `AND`.
I started with on property. When I am trying to filter only one property an error is displayed, which I do not understand.

My stored query

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:StoredQueryDescription xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="test">
<wfs:Parameter name="gemarkungsname" type="xs:string"/>
<wfs:QueryExpressionText isPrivate="false" language="urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFS_QueryExpression" returnFeatureTypes="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f">
    <wfs:Query wfs:typeNames="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f">
        <fes:Filter xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.org/fes/2.0">
            <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>${gemarkungsname}<fes:ValueReference>gemarkungsname</fes:ValueReference></fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </fes:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
</wfs:QueryExpressionText>
```

My `GetFeature` Request in comination with `StoredQuery`

```
http://172.16.206.129:8080/geoserver/KRE_ALKIS/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&StoredQuery_ID=test&gemarkungsname=Beetz&fln=6&fsn_zae=97&fsn_nen=1
```

The error

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://172.16.206.129:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
<ows:ExceptionText>java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for PropertyIsEqualTo: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for PropertyIsEqualTo: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
Parsing failed for PropertyIsEqualTo: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
Index: 1, Size: 1</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

What am I doing wrong?

If I read the capabilities corretly, then I could use `PropertyIsEqualTo` like this. This is a part of getCapabilities:

```
...
<fes:Filter_Capabilities>
    <fes:Conformance>
        <fes:Constraint name="ImplementsQuery">
            <ows:NoValues/>
            <ows:DefaultValue>TRUE</ows:DefaultValue>
        </fes:Constraint>
        <fes:Constraint name="ImplementsAdHocQuery">
            <ows:NoValues/>
            <ows:DefaultValue>TRUE</ows:DefaultValue>
        </fes:Constraint>
        <fes:Constraint name="ImplementsFunctions">
            <ows:NoValues/>
            <ows:DefaultValue>TRUE</ows:DefaultValue>
        </fes:Constraint>
        <fes:Constraint name="ImplementsResourceId">
            <ows:NoValues/>
            <ows:DefaultValue>TRUE</ows:DefaultValue>
        </fes:Constraint>
        <fes:Constraint name="ImplementsMinStandardFilter">
            <ows:NoValues/>
            <ows:DefaultValue>TRUE</ows:DefaultValue>
        </fes:Constraint>
        <fes:Constraint name="ImplementsStandardFilter">
            <ows:NoValues/>
            <ows:DefaultValue>TRUE</ows:DefaultValue>
        </fes:Constraint>
        <fes:Constraint name="ImplementsMinSpatialFilter">
            <ows:NoValues/>
            <ows:DefaultValue>TRUE</ows:DefaultValue>
        </fes:Constraint>
        <fes:Constraint name="ImplementsSpatialFilter">
            <ows:NoValues/>
            <ows:DefaultValue>TRUE</ows:DefaultValue>
        </fes:Constraint>
        <fes:Constraint name="ImplementsMinTemporalFilter">
            <ows:NoValues/>
            <ows:DefaultValue>TRUE</ows:DefaultValue>
        </fes:Constraint>
        <fes:Constraint name="ImplementsTemporalFilter">
            <ows:NoValues/>
            <ows:DefaultValue>TRUE</ows:DefaultValue>
        </fes:Constraint>
        <fes:Constraint name="ImplementsVersionNav">
            <ows:NoValues/>
            <ows:DefaultValue>FALSE</ows:DefaultValue>
        </fes:Constraint>
        <fes:Constraint name="ImplementsSorting">
            <ows:NoValues/>
            <ows:DefaultValue>TRUE</ows:DefaultValue>
        </fes:Constraint>
        <fes:Constraint name="ImplementsExtendedOperators">
            <ows:NoValues/>
            <ows:DefaultValue>FALSE</ows:DefaultValue>
        </fes:Constraint>
        <fes:Constraint name="ImplementsMinimumXPath">
            <ows:NoValues/>
            <ows:DefaultValue>TRUE</ows:DefaultValue>
        </fes:Constraint>
    </fes:Conformance>
    <fes:Id_Capabilities>
        <fes:ResourceIdentifier name="fes:ResourceId"/>
    </fes:Id_Capabilities>
    <fes:Scalar_Capabilities>
        <fes:LogicalOperators/>
        <fes:ComparisonOperators>
            <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsLessThan"/>
            <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsGreaterThan"/>
            <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo"/>
            <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo"/>
            <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsEqualTo"/>
            <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsNotEqualTo"/>
            <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsLike"/>
            <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsBetween"/>
            <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsNull"/>
            <fes:ComparisonOperator name="PropertyIsNil"/>
        </fes:ComparisonOperators>
    </fes:Scalar_Capabilities>
    ...
```

Edit:
With the help of Ian comment I find out the correct why to create this stored query:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:StoredQueryDescription xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="test">
    <wfs:Parameter name="gemarkungsname" type="xs:string"/>
    <wfs:Parameter name="fln" type="xs:string"/>
    <wfs:Parameter name="fsn_zae" type="xs:string"/>
    <wfs:Parameter name="fsn_nen" type="xs:string"/>
    <wfs:QueryExpressionText isPrivate="false" language="urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFS_QueryExpression" returnFeatureTypes="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f:shape">
        <wfs:Query wfs:typeNames="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f">
            <fes:Filter xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.org/fes/2.0">
                <fes:And>
                    <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <fes:PropertyName>
                            <fes:ValueReference>gemarkungsname</fes:ValueReference>
                        </fes:PropertyName>
                        <fes:Literal>${gemarkungsname}</fes:Literal>
                    </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <fes:PropertyName>
                            <fes:ValueReference>fln</fes:ValueReference>
                        </fes:PropertyName>
                        <fes:Literal>${fln}</fes:Literal>
                    </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <fes:PropertyName>
                            <fes:ValueReference>fsn_zae</fes:ValueReference>
                        </fes:PropertyName>
                        <fes:Literal>${fsn_zae}</fes:Literal>
                    </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <fes:PropertyName>
                            <fes:ValueReference>fsn_nen</fes:ValueReference>
                        </fes:PropertyName>
                        <fes:Literal>${fsn_nen}</fes:Literal>
                    </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </fes:And>
            </fes:Filter>
        </wfs:Query>
    </wfs:QueryExpressionText>
</wfs:StoredQueryDescription>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PropertyEquals` takes 2 arguments](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/filter_reference.html#binary-comparison-operators) and you have only provided one.

I suspect that you need to add a `<fes:PropertyName>` tag to

```
<fes:Filter xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.org/fes/2.0">
     <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>${gemarkungsname}<fes:ValueReference>gemarkungsname</fes:ValueReference></fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
 </fes:Filter>
```

Comment: Thank you again Ian. You helped me find the right solution to my problem. I posted my solution at the end of my question. Maybe it will help someone else too

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer so that people can vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: With the help of Ian comment I find out the correct why to create this stored query:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:StoredQueryDescription xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="test">
    <wfs:Parameter name="gemarkungsname" type="xs:string"/>
    <wfs:Parameter name="fln" type="xs:string"/>
    <wfs:Parameter name="fsn_zae" type="xs:string"/>
    <wfs:Parameter name="fsn_nen" type="xs:string"/>
    <wfs:QueryExpressionText isPrivate="false" language="urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFS_QueryExpression" returnFeatureTypes="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f:shape">
        <wfs:Query wfs:typeNames="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f">
            <fes:Filter xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.org/fes/2.0">
                <fes:And>
                    <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <fes:PropertyName>
                            <fes:ValueReference>gemarkungsname</fes:ValueReference>
                        </fes:PropertyName>
                        <fes:Literal>${gemarkungsname}</fes:Literal>
                    </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <fes:PropertyName>
                            <fes:ValueReference>fln</fes:ValueReference>
                        </fes:PropertyName>
                        <fes:Literal>${fln}</fes:Literal>
                    </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <fes:PropertyName>
                            <fes:ValueReference>fsn_zae</fes:ValueReference>
                        </fes:PropertyName>
                        <fes:Literal>${fsn_zae}</fes:Literal>
                    </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <fes:PropertyName>
                            <fes:ValueReference>fsn_nen</fes:ValueReference>
                        </fes:PropertyName>
                        <fes:Literal>${fsn_nen}</fes:Literal>
                    </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </fes:And>
            </fes:Filter>
        </wfs:Query>
    </wfs:QueryExpressionText>
</wfs:StoredQueryDescription>
```